# Directory structures in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

This is something that is frequently confusing me when I try to set up a project in Eclipse using Maven. I understand the basic directory structure imposed by Maven, but when I create a Maven project in Eclipse, it seems even more complicated and convoluted than Maven dictates. There are two almost identical versions of the whole directory. There is the src/main/java... trail at the top, and then the folders are repeated again farther down. Lately I've been working with a Spring project, and there are THREE "copies" of these directories: one is under "Java Resources," the next is under "Deployed Resources," and it's there again simply under the "src" folder. What is the purpose of this repetition? If it's possible to have these directories represented more simply, I'd prefer that, but Eclipse presents an overwhelming variety of options for setting up a project. If I'm using Luna Eclipse, Java, Spring and Maven, what is the SIMPLEST path to follow when creating a new project in a way that keeps this directory mess to a minimum?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I prefer using the Navigator view over the Project Explorer one. Those are _not_ real directories, by the way. They're what Eclipse comes up with after looking at build paths, libraries and so on. After all, when working with Maven I usually try to keep the build process controlled by a standalone maven installation.

Comment: That's much better! Thanks.